# Quasar framework : Navigation guards with file boot doesn't?

Tags: vue.js

i just make register app to test login , register and navigation guards but always i can open the link i will put the code to help me
router/routes.js

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
    children: [
      { 
        path: '', 
        meta:{signIn:true},
        component: () => import('pages/Index.vue')
       },
       { 
        path: 'login', 
        component: () => import('pages/auth.vue')
       },
    ]
  }
]

// Always leave this as last one
if (process.env.MODE !== 'ssr') {
  routes.push({
    path: '*',
    component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue')
  })
}



export default routes
```

this is file boot :boot/router-auth.js

```js
// import something here
import {firebaseAuth} from "boot/firebase"
// "async" is optional
export default  ({ router/* app, router, Vue, ... */ }) => {
  // something to do
  router.beforeEach((to,from,next) =>{
    if(to.matched.some(route =>route.meta.signIn)){
        if(firebaseAuth.currentUser)
        {
          next()
        }else{
        
         //next({ path: "/auth" })
          //Router.push("/auth")
       
            console.log("maldkds");
             next({path:"/login"})
        
          
        }
    } 
     next()
  
      //{ path: "/login" }
 
  })
}
```

and this is my MainLayout.vue

```js
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <q-header elevated>
      <q-toolbar>
   

        <q-toolbar-title class="text-center">
          {{title}}
        </q-toolbar-title>
         <div class="row">
          <q-btn flat dense round v-if="!userDetails.userId" color="white" icon="person" no-caps label="Login" />
          <q-btn flat dense round v-else color="white" icon="person" no-caps @click="logoutUser" >Logout <br/> {{userDetails.name}} </q-btn>
         </div>
        <div></div>
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view  />
    </q-page-container>
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState,mapActions} from "vuex"

export default {
  name: 'MainLayout',


  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed:{
     ...mapState("store",["userDetails"]),
    title(){
      if(this.$route.fullPath=="/"){
       return "Register App"
      } else if(this.$route.fullPath=="/login"){
        return "Auth"
      }

    }
  },
  methods:{
    ...mapActions("store",["logoutUser"]),
  }

}
</script>

<style>
  .q-toolbar .q-btn{
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
</style>
```

Finally i have always this error:

> NavigationDuplicated
>   _name: "NavigationDuplicated" name: "NavigationDuplicated" message: "Navigating to current location ("/login") is not allowed"

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by creating const Router and exporting, after Route, use beforeEach with you validate.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { isAuth, isAdmin, isUser } from "./auth";
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)
const Router = new VueRouter({
  mode: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE,
  base: process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE,
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes
})

Router.beforeEach((to,from, next) => {
  to.matched.some( route =>{
    if(route.meta.requiresAuth){
      if(!isAuth()){
        next({ path: '/' })
      }
    }
    next()
  })
})
export default Router
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `debugger` as the first line of your `router.beforeEach()` and examine what is inside `to.matched`. It is possible that it is matching the route with path `''` and it may redirect `/login` to `/login`, aka. redirect loop.